# gpg: --sign, --clear-sign, --detach-sign

Tags: gnupg, signing, pgp

I am making this question because I didn't find a clear explanation about the difference between these 3 gpg options:

```sh
gpg --sign file        # produces file.gpg
gpg --clear-sign file  # produces file.asc
gpg --detach-sign file # produces file.sig
```

`file.gpg` and `file.sig` seem to be binary files, while `file.asc` seems to be a text file. What is the relationship between these 3 files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html

Basically when signing with `--detach-sign` the resulting .sig won't contain the signed file only the signature.
`--sign` compresses, signs and outputs the signed text in a binary format.
`--clearsign` wraps the text in an ASCII-armored signature

Comment: `--sign` does not encrypt files!

Comment: Is `--clearsign` any different from `--armor --sign`?

Comment: Yes. With `--sign --armor` the cleartext isn't show, and the ascii will be different because the armor includes both the message and the signature. `--clearsign` is more similar to `--detach-sign --armor`, which is exactly the ascii that shows up after the cleartext.